# How to Downgrade ForgeRock AM from 720 to 653

Tags: upgrade, openam, downgrade, forgerock

We are planning to upgrade the AM from 653 to 720 in coming releases.

to protect ourself from any failures in products we want to plan the rollback of AM from 720 to 653.

We know there is "Config-Upgrader" tool available with AM7 which in transform AM 653 configurations into AM720.

but I did not find any tool or document which can help me transform AM720 configuration into AM 653.

Please let me know the tool/process to downgrade the OpenAm from 720 to 653

Comment: why don't you have a back up of the configuration in the first place ?